# What does the Chrome password manager icon represent?

Tags: google-chrome

When Google Chrome remembers a password, it shows an icon in the address bar that looks like a hammer. What is it and how does it conceptually relate to passwords?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because it is not a symbol of a hammer, it is a symbol of a key. If you look closely at it, it may look like a hammer but it's actually key.

Comment: Huh, I guess you're right. Rubbish icon, IMO.